# Real Analysis Differential functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

I am currently working through an exercise set and I am a little stuck on the following question:

For $a > 0$, define a function $f_a(x)= \begin{cases} x^a \sin(1/x), &x \ne 0\\0, &x=0 \end{cases}$

Find values of $a$ such that:

a) $f_a$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ but $f^1_a$ is unbounded on $[0,1]$.

Help will be appreciated!

Comment: It will be good if you can mention what made you think '$a$' should be less than zero

Comment: So you claim that the *positive* values of $a$ are exactly the *negative* ones?

Comment: Ahh, my mistake. Back to the drawing board :S

Comment: Can anyone help me get started?